# Proper way to suspend application while separate threads are working

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm using a library that listens for incoming TCP messages (it uses BeginAcceptTcpClient). It's intended to work in the background, while my app does other data processing. After it opens some separate threads reading data from the internet, lets the main application thread to continue.

When testing, I used to use it that way:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    [...]

    connectionsManager.Start();

    logger.LogInformation("Application started");

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

When I'm testing it locally, it works as intended: I can open the application and it works until I press `Enter`. But now I decided to run it on VPS using docker. It turns out that when I run a docker container as a background app, it closes right after writing "Application started" to the logger. `Console.ReadLine()` doesn't suspend main thread and even if other threads are still working in `connectionManager`, the app closes.

Of course, I can make an infinite loop, but are there any better ways to do that? I don't want to waste processing power on irrelevant operations.

Comment: Task.Delay(cancellationtoken) would be similar, but I would probably get a rerence to your asnc threads and wait for them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple way of achieving that is

```
Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
```

You can find the `Timeout` class in the `System.Threading` namespace, but in reality, `Infinite` is just a `const` with a value of `-1`.

For async you can go

```
await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite);
```

Comment: You should wait on the cancellation token, otherwise shutting down in docker works not as good.

Comment: The question is about suspending a thread while avoiding both busy waiting and signals coming from STDIN. It just so happens that without Docker, the person asking the question had no intention to avoid waiting for STDIN and now they are. What `CancellationToken` instance are you talking about? Are you saying there exists a .NET Core provided `CancellationToken` instance which listens to `SIGTERM`? What API should I call to obtain it?

Comment: @dumitru https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2018/june/clean-service-stop-on-linux-with-net-core-21/ Is an example for using the Hosting for that.